# Same Html different table

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have very complex table used for reporting.
Below html code is generated through react.
It is valid bootstrap 4 and html code.
Each time it generates a different table output

```
<table class="text-center table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table-secondary">
            <td rowspan="4" colspan="1" style="vertical-align: middle;">Area / Department</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">Station Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Station No</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Location Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">129</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Recovery Room</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="text-center table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table-secondary">
            <td rowspan="4" colspan="1" style="vertical-align: middle;">Area / Department</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">Station Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Station No</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Location Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">130</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Bonded Warehouse</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Output for above html]

How can I generate same layout each time

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have edited above question

Comment: It's because of the varying text size in your table contents. You can just have a fix width fr the `<td>` to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't:  behavior changes based on content.

Try with some CSS style, for example give a unique width to each cell.

```
td { width: 150px; }
```